# Is it ok to minimise the style of attributions in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, bing-maps, copyright-display, attribution

I develop a website that contains a full size OpenLayers map that uses Bing Maps as layer.
This website will be displayed on computers and mobile phones.

When I clicked on the Openlayers attributions button, I discovered that it's using a lot of space and it's ugly for mobile experience.

See:

[image: OL attributions]

In my example I put it at the top-left corner while the default is at the bottom-right corner. It doesn't really matter at the end.

My question is, what are the limits of customization of such attributions while still being OK with the terms of use or whatever other legal stuff?

For example, I was thinking about reducing the font size to make it a bit smaller, but I didn't find any information regarding the limit size in pixels or about modifying any styling stuff like that.

Comment: OpenLayers uses a single default font size for all attributions, some data provider do specify a minimum size but I can't find anything in the Bing terms.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the attribution panel in it's closed state (shows an info icon "i"). The content of the attribution should not change.